# Pooled and NonPooled connections

Tags: c#, postgresql, connection-pooling, npgsql, performancecounter

My application is running on Windows Server 2106 with 24 CPU and 16 GB RAM, using PostgreSql 11.2 as a database on a separate CentOS 7 server. Application is written with C# 4.7.1 using Npgsql 4.0.6.

Generally (with 100-200 concurrent connections) everything works fine. However, during heavier load (400-500 concurrent connections) there were some 'freezes' - server stopped processing new requests, hanged for several seconds, then continued working normally.

After trying several configurations, we have increased CPU count on DB server from 8 to 16. Freezes were eliminated until there were about 700 concurrent connections. So, my attention become focused (along with couple of other ideas) on working with database.

I've installed Npgsql performance counters as described by [Npgsql docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/performance.html#performance-counters) and modified ConnectionString as follows:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseConnectionString" value="Server=dbserver;Port=5432;Database=mydb;User Id=postgres;Password=mypass;CommandTimeout=30;Use Perf Counters=true" />
</appSettings>
```

Documentation states that [Npgsql uses pooling by default](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html), However, 
Performance Monitor shows that values of NumberOfNonPooledConnections and NumberOfPooledConnections counters are the same all the time and they equal to 24 - the number of cores on App server. NumberOfActiveConnectionPools counter is 1, all other counters are 0.

Does it mean that there are only 24 non-pooled connections for my 700 concurrent requests? Is it the expected behavior? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your answers and suggestions

Comment: Were you running the perf mon while the app was under load, or was it mostly idle? The pool grows and shrinks as needed. I think the default max is 100 and apparently the default min is 1 per core.

Comment: The performance counter feature is *somewhat* untested - the best way to now how many connections you have at a given moment is to query on the PostgreSQL side via pg_stat_activity (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html).

Comment: @JohnWu under load connections increased to 27 then gradually dropped to 24 and stayed there

Comment: @ShayRojansky pg_stat_activity shows 2-8 active connections, others are idle, total number corresponds to connections counter value.
Strange thing is that NumberOfNonPooledConenctions is the same as NumberOfPooledConnections